# Date math on the Google Calendar events

Tags: google-apps-script

We have a STR (Airbnb) and I import that calendar in the google calendar account, however for some reasons the imported date/time doesn't match my local timezone.

We want our cleaning crew to coordinate around the guest checking in/out, but I'm do not want them to import the Airbnb calendar directly. My thought is that I'd copy the event from the subscribed calendar (Airbnb) to my calendar dynamically. This way I have better control of access.

I found a script https://gist.github.com/AndrewSouthpaw/5ef5798d46a4ee159e05ef5a477b542d that does similar things, and I could get this script to copy the event from the subscribed calendar to my calendar.

However App script doesn't allow me to do date math on the entries.

For instance, I can successfully obtain the current event detail using the getEndTime() function
`Logger.log("AirBnb event detail Endtime - " + evi.getEndTime())` but I couldn't update the DateTime variable.

I tried this from the docs and it works

```
const MILLIS_Offset = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
const now = new Date()
Logger.log("now - " + now)

const tomorrow = new Date(now.getTime() + MILLIS_Offset)
Logger.log("tomorrow - " + tomorrow)
```

but when I try the following it doesn't

```
 var curDate = new Date(evi.getEndTime())
 Logger.log(curDate)

 var offSetDate = new Date(curDate + 2*MILLIS_Offset)
 Logger.log("Offset time - " + offSetDate )
```

In this case the curDate & offSetDate are exactly the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no getEndTime() method for Javascript Date() object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myfunk() {
  const dt = new Date();
  const da = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;//milliseconds in a day
  Logger.log(dt)
  var offSetDate = new Date(dt.valueOf() + (2 * da))
  Logger.log("Offset time - " + offSetDate);//2 day difference
}

Execution log
3:30:29 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:30:26 PM  Info    Sun Sep 24 15:30:26 GMT-06:00 2023
3:30:26 PM  Info    Offset time - Tue Sep 26 2023 15:30:26 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
3:30:30 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Thanks, @Cooper, it worked perfectly!